# Techniques used for Stockfish engine selectivity

Tags: engines, stockfish, programming, evaluation

Example puzzle (I'm sure there are numerous that fit this bill):

```
[FEN "rnbq3r/pppp4/3b1pkp/5p2/2BP4/4P3/PPP2PPP/RN1QK2R w KQ - 0 1"]
[Site "Earth"]
[White ""]

1. Qh5+ Kxh5 2. Bf7+ Kh4 3. Nd2 Bb4 4. c3 f4 5. Nf3+ Kg4 6. e4 Bxc3+ 7. bxc3 f5 8. h3#
```

I've found a 8 move checkmate that takes Stockfish a depth of 36 ply to solve. Since the checkmate is only 16 ply deep in the game search tree, what *specific* mechanisms cause the engine to take *20 ply* longer to find the solution?

I understand that the high level answer is [engine selectivity](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Selectivity). However, my understanding is that Stockfish's forward pruning tended to be pretty safe (such as [null move pruning](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Null_Move_Pruning)). Plus, if the solution were being forward pruned, *wouldn't it keep being pruned even at later depths*?

I also thought that [reductions](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Reductions) such as [late move reductions](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Late_Move_Reductions#Reduction_Depth) only really reduce the search depth by a one or a few ply, not 20!

(The winning move is a check, so it shouldn't be reduced by something like late move reduction anyways.)

What gives?

([Crossposted](https://www.reddit.com/r/ComputerChess/comments/p6k3jl/techniques_used_for_stockfish_engine_selectivity/)...will be sure to update if anything comes of it)

Comment: Enumerating the exact set of techniques in action here might be too difficult, but I'd really appreciate if anyone could give me a general idea of where my thought process might be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who stumbles across this wondering the same thing, I received an answer to my question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ComputerChess/comments/p6k3jl/techniques_used_for_stockfish_engine_selectivity/). This post is thus a courtesy of [u/__Durandal__](https://www.reddit.com/user/__Durandal__/) and [IMJorose](https://www.reddit.com/user/IMJorose/). Though I can't do justice to their write-ups and highly recommend them, in case it somehow goes down, I'll summarize the gist here.

The reduction techniques in Stockfish are *not* limited to just one or two ply—late move reductions, for example, are calculated based on the number of moves already searched and the current depth. In the current implementation:

> If a position has 40 moves in it and is searched at depth 16, the reduction applied is five plies.

Furthermore, any potentially-unsafe pruning techniques (i.e. avoiding entire part of the tree) have a depth cap at which they stop operating. These two phenomena explain what I was seeing.

Notably, given infinite time, Stockfish will still converge to the minimax solution: reduction techniques become inconsequential at infinite depth and depth caps mean that nothing will be overlooked via pruning.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this, but I think one can get some insight into this by examining how Leela's Monte Carlo Tree Search works. Leela's neural network gives 1) a win percentage for that position, and 2) a list of candidate moves to consider, each with a probability. Leela then uses that probability in its searches. For example, if the neural network is 99% confident that a particular move is correct, then Leela will spend 99% (?) of its time looking at that move.

*However*, it will also eventually look at the remaining 1%. It will de-emphasize the other moves, and it will spend less time looking at those moves, but it will do so eventually.

I think that's what you're seeing here. The key first move gives away a Queen for no apparent compensation, so Stockfish de-emphasizes it. However, after it has searched the mainlines to very high depth (d=36), it goes back and looks at the moves it earlier de-emphasized. It finds that 1.Qh5+ is better, and this line becomes promoted to the new principal variation.

I do not know the technical details, however.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab! From what I understand, you're absolutely correct. This explains how Leela might respond to the puzzle. I guess I'm looking for the alpha/beta search equivalent of this monte carlo tree search characteristic. It's almost like we get there with late move reductions, but I didn't think they could go as far as 20 ply.